# Laravel - Show User Profile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a social network type of website using Laravel 4 and I have user profiles. I have no problem creating an account and viewing my own profile when logged in, but I am unable to view other test profiles (logged in or not) or my own profile when not logged in.  So if I type www.MyWebsite.com/user/SomeUserName I get the following error.

I realize that my issue has something to do with it only recognizing the user as whoever the authenicated user is (so there is no User object when no one is authenticated), but how do I bring up somone else's profile without being logged in/logged in and viewing a profile other than my own so I can add someone as a friend? Do I apply a filter to the route and pass the username requested as a parameter?

Thanks in advance for the help!

> ### ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\athletus\app\views\profile\user.blade.php)

```
// Route to user profile
Route::get('/user/{username}', array(
    'as' => 'profile-user',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@user',
));


//ProfileController
<?php
class ProfileController extends BaseController {
public function user($user) {

    $user = User::where('username', '=' , $user);

    if($user->count()) {
        $user = $user->first();

        return View::make('profile.user')
            ->with('user', $user);
    }

    return App::abort(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: `View: C:\xampp\htdocs\athletus\app\views\profile\user.blade.php` your error is in the view, in the user.blade.php page, not in the code you provided

Comment: You are correct....not sure why I couldn't see that before.  Probably because it is 3:26AM and I have been coding for hours now.  Problem solved!!!  Thanks again!